# How to configure Cygwin for key-based login

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I have successfully installed Cygwin on my 2012 server.

Now, I want to enable key-based login.

I have searched a lot for this ( I'm not a linux guru ) and everything I have found orbits around adding the key to /.ssh/authorized_keys file.

The problem is that I can't find the .ssh folder to create the file and add the key to it.

Some posts suggested to check if home variable is defined or not by executing

```
echo $HOME
```

command and see if it will output anything or not.

The outpu was

```
$ echo $HOME
/home/admin
```

I already have the key generated from the client machine. I just want to know where to put it.

I have found [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/36278/how-to-set-up-ssh-sshd-for-key-based-login-under-cygwin-vista-with-strictmodes) but I couldn't get the exact steps from it.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to run `ssh-copy-id user@host`, which will copy your public keys to correct location on `host`.

Copying it by hand causes frequently access rights issues.

Comment: Should this command be executed on local machine or on the server ?

Comment: On local machine, where you have your keys

Answer (score 0):

For those without "ssh-copy-id" installed, or those who are temporarily-unable to install it for whatever reason, the following Bash one-liner is always a valid substitute:

`$ PUB="$(cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)"; ssh user@host "mkdir -p ~/.ssh; echo $PUB >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys; chmod 700 ~/.ssh; chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"`

The tilde-slash (~/) on the remote host probably isn't needed, but I include it just in case, in order to avoid any weird and/or unforeseen scenarios.

Comment: Thanks @rubynorails and sorry for being late, I was away for some time.
Should I run this command on Cygwin terminal on the client or on my windows server ?

Comment: This whole thing relies on the fact that you have `ssh` installed on both machines, with `sshd` listening on the remote host on the standard port 22 (unless otherwise configured in your local `ssh_config`.  If you are trying to setup authentication from local-to-remote, you will execute this command on the local host, and replace `user@host` with [your remote username]@[remote host/ip].  I hope this helps.